# How to pass a string to the Javascript function from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, hyperlink

I have a dynamic **Html table** in which there is a cell that contains anchor tag. Along with the anchor tag, I'm calling a function thru **OnClick** method. That function takes two parameter and both are **String** type.

In that, one string contains the value like this **"PUT Request|GET Request|JDBC Request|"**

**Example:**

```
<td align='center'><a href='#' title='click here' onclick=showTestCaseReport('" 
+ tcId + "','" + strStep + "')>Detail</a></td>
```

**JavaScript function:**

```
function showTestCaseReport(testCaseId, testSteps)
{
    alert(testCaseId);
    alert(testSteps);
}
```

But when click on the click i.e. **Detail** from the browser, Javascript alert is not displaying as per the function defined.

**EDITED:** After analysed, I came to know that the String value that I had mentioned above has white space in the middle. After removing the white spaces like this **PUTRequest|GETRequest|JDBCRequest|**, its working.

**Ques:** Is there any way to handle this without removing the white space in the middle of the string values?

Thanks

Comment: Please check the argument value .

Comment: The problem is that you neglected to properly quote the `onclick` attribute value. You are generating `onclick=showTestCaseReport("PUT Request|...")`, so of course the actual attribute value the HTML parser reads from that is just `showTestCaseReport("PUT`

Comment: People are still using inline handlers in 2018?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onclick attribute is missing quotes please add them correctly and proceed
See this https://jsbin.com/viqosobizo/edit?html,output

```
<td align='center'><a href='#' title='click here' onclick="showTestCaseReport('hello','great');">Detail</a></td>
```

Comment: see the link in answer

Comment: @Karunagara that _does_ work, if you handle the rest of the quotes correctly as well. But if you are using `"` as the delimiter of the parameter value you are passing to the `showTestCaseReport` function, then of course you have the same problem again ... `onclick="showTestCaseReport("foo bar")"` - these inner quotes need to either be escaped, or substituted for single ones, `'`

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing how you create that table. Assuming you have your `<td>` wrapped in quotes too, you need to either escape them or use data attributes (recommended)

```
"<td align='center'><a href='#' title='click here'"+
" data-tcId='"+tcId+"' data-strStep='"+strStep+"'"+ 
" onclick='return showTestCaseReport(this)'>Detail</a></td>"
```

Then

```
function showTestCaseReport(cell) {
  var testCaseId = cell.getAttribute("data-tcId"),
      testSteps  = cell.getAttribute("data-strStep");
  ....
  return false; // cancel link
}
```